# Как включить поддержку import в node js?

Tags: node.js

Пишу код

```
import create from './create'
```

А у меня ошибка:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Сервер запускаю так

```
node server
```

---

Можно добавить параметр 
node --experimental-modules server
И переименовать файл server.js в server.mjs.
Но при это перестаёт работать require

---

А можно ли как то настроить такое поведение по умолчанию? Чтобы не писать лишние аргументы. Чтобы работало и module и require?

Comment: А зачем вам в одном и том же файле использовать и import и require одновременно?

Comment: На данный момент нормальной поддержки нету, если очень нужно, то можно использовать `Babel`

Comment: Просто много файлов проекта написано через require. 
А сейчас хочется всё новое что будет разрабатываться перевести на import. 
Получается это 2 несовместимые системы модулей, либо как то можно (через babel ) всё таки их подружить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выдержка из документации по [Node.js v10.8.0](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/esm.html):

> Флаг `--experimental-modules` может использоваться для включения функций
>   для загрузки модулей ESM.
>
> Как только это будет установлено, файлы, заканчивающиеся на `.mjs`,
>   будут загружаться в виде модулей ES.
>
> ```
> node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs
> ```

Answer (score -1):

`ts-node` отлично работает для этих целей, если набор js-фишек в тайпскрипте вас устраивает

`ts-node index.js`